# How to add footer to Google Slides?

Tags: google-slides

I seek to add a footer to Google Slides: "Attorney client .....".

- Is this possible?
- How is a footer added once so that the change is applied to each slide?

Comment: did you try adding it via print menu?

Comment: I added a text box to the master slide.

Answer (score 15):

The option is not explicit but you can do it.
Go to **Insert -> Text box** and make a box where you want your footer, with what you want in it (I suggest centering it horizontally).

Then **Right-click** on the box and select **Add to Theme** -> Master / [...].

Adding to Master will put it on all slides.
If you select something else, it will put it on all slides of that theme (*e.g.* the "Title and body" theme).